# Select latest records and add results as new columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following database
[image]

my StudentRecords for specific sutdent is
[image]

How can i get the latest 3 `studentRecords` based on the latest `Records.RecordDate` 
so for each sutdent, row will have `ReportItems.ReportItemName ReportItems.TotalPSR,, Students.FullName`, + add the following columns:
The latest studentRecords based on `RecordDate` and display the psr + reordsNames + recordDate so that one row look like this

[image]

Is this even possible?
And how can i do this using EF6 also what will be the SQL select statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing your EF entities are set up with their mappings correctly to associate the Students, StudentRecords, and Records then you should be able to accomplish this in EF using something like the following:

```
var results = testContext.Students
    .SelectMany(s => s.StudentRecords.OrderByDescending(sr => sr.Record.RecordDate).Take(3))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Student)
    .ToList();
```

What this will give you is a result per-student in a grouped structure where the grouping is on the student, with the grouped values are StudentResults. From there you can extract the student details from the "Key", while each result is a collection of (up to) 3 latest StudentRecords in descending order. You will need to handle the scenario where the # of results is < 3.

As a simple example extraction...

```
foreach (var studentGrouping in results)
{
   studentName = studentGrouping.Key.FullName;
   psr1 = studentGrouping[0].PSR;
   recordName1 = studentGrouping[0].Record.RecordName;
   recordDate1 = studentGrouping[0].Record.RecordDate;
   // ... etc.
}
```

Now a caveat to the above solution is that it will invoke lazy-loading on the Records, so up to 3 hits per student. Curiously I tried to mitigate this with .Include(s=>s.StudentRecords.Select(r=>r.Record)) or trying the .Include(r=> r.Record) after the SelectMany() but while the initial query looked to include the columns for the Records, it still triggered the lazy loads.

*If anyone can offer a correction to address the lazy loads, I'd love to hear it. I was a bit surprised to see them after adding the Include statements.*

If your object model is more complex, such as lots of fields in Student/Record, etc. then I would recommend altering the above to return an anonymous type structure to retrieve just the values you're going to need to populate your results. The above is Ok for simple structures.

For example if Student had 30 columns, but we only care about the ID and Name:

```
var results = testContext.Students
    .SelectMany(s => s.StudentRecords.OrderByDescending(sr => sr.Record.RecordDate).Take(3))
    .Select( sr=> new {sr.Student.StudentId, sr.Student.FullName, sr.PSR, sr.Record.RecordId, RecordName = sr.Record.Name})
    .GroupBy(x => new{StudentId, FullName})
    .ToList();
```

This would return a structure where the Key was an anonymous type containing just the StudentId and Name, with the grouped values being the type containing the record details for that student. This has the benefit of only returning the data you will need in a single query to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Row_Number and Pivot as below:

```
;With Cte as (
    Select RI.ReportItemName, RI.TotalPSR, S.FullName, SR.PSR, R.[Name], R.[Date], 
        RowNPSR = Row_Number() over(Partition by SR.StudentRecord order by R.RecordDate DESC),
        RowName = Row_Number() over(Partition by SR.StudentRecord order by R.RecordDate DESC) + 500,
        RowDate = Row_Number() over(Partition by SR.StudentRecord order by R.RecordDate DESC) + 1000
    from
        StudentRecords SR
        Join Students s
        on SR.StudentId = S.StudentId
        Join Records R
        On SR.RecordId = R.recordId
        Left Join ReportItems RI
        On S.ReportItemId = RI.ReportItemId
) 
Select a.*, p1.[1] as PSR1, p1.[2] as PSR2, p1.[3] as PSR3
        , p2.[501] as Name1, p2.[502] as Name2, p2.[503] as Name3 from (
    Select * from CTE RowNPSR <= 3 ) a
    Pivot (max(PSR) for RowNPSR in ([1],[2],[3]) ) p1
    Pivot (max([Name]) for RowName in ([501],[502],[503]) ) p2
    Pivot (max([Date]) for RowDate in ([1001],[1002],[1003]) ) p3
```

Comment: It doen't compile,